# How to calculate conversion exchange fees?

Tags: exchanges, exchange-fees

According to Exchange A, I can withdraw 1 BTC as `90 fiat`. Or I can send them 1 fiat in return for `0.01 BTC`. How do I calculate percentage fees for one way conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The formula to calculate that is:

```
100% x (1-√(BTC x fiat))
```

where `BTC` and `fiat` are the two values highlighted in gray above.

Using the values given in the quesiton, it is `5.1%`.

(Assuming that the conversion fees in both ways are calculated as a percentage, with the multiplier)